# How to create a virtual file system with offline files (similar to OneDrive) in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, onedrive, virtualfilesystem

I need to create a virtual file system that syncs files from my Azure app service to local drive and backward. I need only some files and folders to be synchronized to my local file system and be available offline. The files/folders should synchronize during first access or when the user selects the "Always keep on this device" menu. Similar to how OneDrive is doing. I found the Microsoft CloudMirror C++ sample which has some basic OneDrive functionality, but it syncs all files one time during start and no listing/loading on first access.

Is it possible to build virtual file system with above functionality completely in .NET?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To build an OneDrive-like client you need to create the Sync Provider using cloud filter API, which is mostly programmable via Win32 (with some exceptions, see below), but you can build a complete OneDrive analog in .NET, including "Always keep on this device" menu and on-demand loading.

**Here is the functionality that is available via .NET**, so you do not need to PInvoke it:

- Sync root registration can be done in .NET, via the [StorageProviderSyncRootManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.storageprovidersyncrootmanager) and [StorageProviderSyncRootInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.storageprovidersyncrootinfo) classes.
- You can create properties in .NET using [StorageProviderItemProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.storageprovideritemproperty) class and [IStorageProviderItemPropertySource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.istorageprovideritempropertysource) interface.
- Icons in Windows File Manager on files and folders can be set via [StorageProviderItemProperties.SetAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.storageprovideritemproperties.setasync) method and StorageFile/StorageFolder class.
- You can read and set file attributes in .NET using [File.GetAttributes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getattributes) / [File.SetAttributes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setattributes). You will need them to read offline attribute, pinned and unpinned attributes.
- File system path to URI mapping can be done via implementing [IStorageProviderUriSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.istorageproviderurisource) interface.

**Here is functionality available via Win32 functions only**, you will need to call it via PInvoke:

- Folders on-demand enumeration, on-demand file content loading is available via Win32 callback only. You will need to register callback using [CfConnectSyncRoot()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfconnectsyncroot).
- Files hydration/dehydration via Windows Explorer menus. You will need to monitor the file system and call [CfHydratePlaceholder()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfhydrateplaceholder) and [CfUpdatePlaceholder()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfupdateplaceholder).
- Download progress reporting, error reporting, notifications to Windows, sync provider status reporting. To report progress use the [CfReportProviderProgress()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfreportproviderprogress). Errors are reported via [CfExecute()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfexecute).
- Detection is the file is a regular file/folder or a placeholder file/folder. Can be done via [CfGetPlaceholderStateFromFileInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfgetplaceholderstatefromfileinfo) call.
- Creation of placeholders and update of placeholder's info. Can be done using [CfCreatePlaceholders()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfcreateplaceholders) and [CfUpdatePlaceholder()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfupdateplaceholder) functions.
- Converting files/folders into placeholders and back. Can be done using [CfConvertToPlaceholder()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfconverttoplaceholder) and [CfRevertPlaceholder()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfrevertplaceholder).
- Setting and reading placeholder statuses, such as in-sync/not in-sync. Can be done using [CfGetPlaceholderStateFromFileInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfgetplaceholderstatefromfileinfo) and [CfGetPlaceholderInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfgetplaceholderinfo).

**Here is what you can do to write all code in .NET:**

- One option is to [import all required Win32 functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2003/july/net-column-calling-win32-dlls-in-csharp-with-p-invoke) using extern to .NET, for example:

  ```
   [DllImport("cldapi.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
   public static extern int CfGetPlaceholderStateFromFileInfo(IntPtr infoBuffer, FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS infoClass);

   [DllImport("cldapi.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
   public static extern HRESULT CfSetPinState(IntPtr fileHandle, int pinState, int pinFlags, IntPtr overlapped);
  ```
- Another option could be [using this sample](https://github.com/ITHit/UserFileSystemSamples/tree/master/Windows/VirtualFileSystem).

Some more notes on building an OneDrive-like file system:

- The "Always keep on this device"/"Free up space" shows automatically on sync root registration. But it only sets Pinned and Unpinned file attributes. You need to monitor the file system, examine the pinned/unpinned attributes, and hydrate/dehydrate each file.
- The on-demand folders listing is done inside the CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_FETCH_PLACEHOLDERS callback. You need to register callback using [CfConnectSyncRoot()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfconnectsyncroot) and listen to it in .NET code.
- The on-demand file content download (hydration) is done inside the CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_FETCH_DATA callback. You need to register and listen to it in .NET code.

Comment: what callback does clicking "Always keep on this device"/"Free up space" should I listen to? I am not getting any FileSystemWatcher callback or CF callback

Comment: If adding attributes to notifyfilter sends that event, how can I differentiate between last write time vs attributes in callback